Azure Data Factory 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input'
I am trying to run a copy data activity from an API to an Azure SQL database. The pipeline activity is getting an error of

ErrorCode=InvalidParameter, 'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException, Message=The value of the property 'input' is invalid: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input'., Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentNullException,Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,

There is no parameter named input in any of the code. Not the pipeline activity, not the datasets, and not in the linked services.
Here is the pipeline code:
{
    "name": "pipeline8",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "JsonSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "HttpReadSettings",
                            "requestMethod": "POST",
                            "requestTimeout": ""
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                        "writeBehavior": "insert",
                        "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
                        "disableMetricsCollection": false
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "SkyPrepDataset",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "relativeurl": "get_users?"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSQLDataset",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "schemaname": "dbo",
                            "tablename": "webuser",
                            "sqlserver": "myserver",
                            "sqldb": "mydb"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "folder": {
            "name": "SkyPrep"
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}

Here is the source dataset:
{
    "name": "SkyPrepDataset",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "SkyPrepHTTPAPI",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "relativeurl": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "Json",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "HttpServerLocation",
                "relativeUrl": {
                    "value": "@dataset().relativeurl",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        "schema": {}
    }
}

Here is the sink dataset
{
    "name": "AzureSQLDataset",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureSqlDatabase",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference",
            "parameters": {
                "sqlserver": {
                    "value": "@dataset().sqlserver",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "sqldb": {
                    "value": "@dataset().sqldb",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        "parameters": {
            "schemaname": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "tablename": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sqlserver": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sqldb": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureSqlTable",
        "schema": [],
        "typeProperties": {
            "schema": {
                "value": "@dataset().schemaname",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "table": {
                "value": "@dataset().tablename",
                "type": "Expression"
            }
        }
    }
}

here is the source linked service
{
    "name": "AzureSqlDatabase",
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "sqlserver": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sqldb": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureSqlDatabase",
        "typeProperties": {
            "server": "@{linkedService().sqlserver}",
            "database": "@{linkedService().sqldb}",
            "encrypt": "mandatory",
            "trustServerCertificate": false,
            "authenticationType": "SystemAssignedManagedIdentity"
        }
    }
}

and the sink linked service
{
    "name": "SkyPrepHTTPAPI",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "HttpServer",
        "typeProperties": {
            "url": "https://api.skyprep.io/admin/api/",
            "enableServerCertificateValidation": true,
            "authenticationType": "Anonymous",
            "authHeaders": {
                "api_key": {
                    "type": "SecureString",
                    "value": "**********"
                },
                "acct_key": {
                    "type": "SecureString",
                    "value": "**********"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Can you add your source and sink

The Source is an API and the Sink is an Azure SQL Database


ErrorCode=InvalidParameter,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The value of the property 'input' is invalid: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input'.,Source=,''Type=System.ArgumentNullException,Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,

The above error can cause due to several reasons as follow:

Parameter created in pipeline/dataset/linkedservice and parameter used in pipeline/dataset/linkedservice are case sensitive. To avoid this problem, keep the parameter name in both locations the same
Check Dynamic Parameters you passed in Pipeline are correct and have proper values to it.
Check source and sink connection before running pipeline if it is succeeding or not then further use it in pipeline.


The parameters all have the same case. The issue is that I am getting an error on a parameter 'input', which is not a parameter anywhere in the pipeline. Not the copy activity, the datasets, or the linked services.
There are no dynamic parameters.
Both the source and sink connection are successfully connecting. I can call the API directly with a Web activity, but not a copy data activity.
